# Do two atomic nuclei interact with each other?

Tags: atomic-physics

I am exploring physics through youtube documentaries and wikipedia mostly. I do not understand though if two atomic nuclei ( two atoms with a nucleus) interact with each other. I can think of two ways right now: 
1. Atoms interact with each other by only exchanging electrons. Atomic nucleus can change its structure/composition.
2.Atoms interact with each other by exchanging electrons and fermions.
Which of those two stands true or if none of them stands true, can you please explain in simple terms the correct answer.

Comment: Fermions are particles that obey Fermi-Dirac statistics. The electron is an example of a fermion. Depending on the energy scale of the interaction, atoms can interact with each other in different ways. The "electron exchange" picture is usually described so in chemistry because the energy scale at play is around several electronvolts. Nuclear reactions that change the structure of the nuclei happen at megaelectronvolts to gigaelectronvolts energy scale.

Comment: It's unclear whether you mean an interaction strong (deep?) enough to change the nuclei themselves or merely changes electromagnetic fields surrounding the nuclei.  Do not answer in a comment! Edit your question to clarify your intent.